# Approximating infinite sum

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am looking for a way to approximate the following expression, with given $s$, $\alpha$, and $c$ (which is always positive).

$$
\sum_{x = n+1}^\infty \frac{1}{x^s \sum_{i=1}^{x-1} \left( \left( \sum_{j=i}^\infty j^{-s} \right)^\alpha e^{-\alpha c(i)} \right)}
$$

I suspect there's no way that's better than just brute computing, especially because I have not specified $c$, but I'd appreciate any pointers.

Comment: See [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Please provide more context and details - why is this sum important to you? Where does it come from? Information like this will help potential answerers decide what kind of information you will find useful and what you will not.

Comment: You might play with differentiating with respect to $s$ and/or $\alpha$, or even introducing new parameters that you can differentiate to see if doing so will modify the formula in a way that you can sum. Or produce a differential equation that can be solved to find a generating function. It is difficult to find a useful trick, but if you do, it can tell you a lot about the expression.